# Why my variable is undefined when I'm using an arrow function onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render, arrow-functions

In my react component, orders[i] is defined, since the component is rendered using name and amount, however, when it comes to onClick event, orders[i] is undefined in the context of the arrow function. How can I call that function using orders[i].name as an argument?

```
let orders = this.state.orders;
let ordersRender =[];
for (var i=0; i<orders.length; i++) {
  if (orders[i].amount) {
    let newInvoiceItem = <InvoiceItem name={orders[i].name} amount ={orders[i].amount} key={i} handleDelete={() => this.deleteProduct(orders[i].name)}/>;
    ordersRender.push(newInvoiceItem);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `handleDelete` event is fired, the variable `i` has changed its value to `orders.length`, that's why `orders[i]` is undefined when `onClick` is fired.

So, instead of `for-loop`, use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the orders and return an array of `InvoiceItem` items. Since `amount` is optional, we need to filter the orders based on the amount before applying the `.map` function.

```
let { orders } = this.state;
let ordersRender = orders.filter(order => order.amount).map(({name, amount}, index) => {
  return (
    <InvoiceItem name={name} amount ={amount} key={index} handleDelete={() => this.deleteProduct(name)}/>
  );
})
...
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing var to let solves this issue.